# How to convert value #define'd in a macro to a char* (c++)

Tags: c++, macros, directory

In a .cpp, I want to output a file to a directory created at compile time (determined by the time of compilation). I have passed this value via -DCOMPILETIME=$(stuff about time) in my makefile. I would like to pass the value stored in COMPILETIME to sprintf so I can create a filepath string to eventually use to place my output file.

I have tried:

```
#define str(x) #x
sprintf(filepath,"\"%s\file\"",str(COMPILETIME));
```

as well as

```
#define str(x) #x
#define strname(name) str(name)
sprintf(filepath,"\"%s\file\"",strname(COMPILETIME));
```

but I only ever get

```
"COMPILETIME/file"
```

as output.

Comment: That's exactly what you should expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macros are fine. Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define str(x) #x
#define strname(name) str(name)

int main()
{
   printf("\"%s/file\"\n",strname(COMPILETIME));
   return 0;
}
```

Build command:

```
cc -Wall -o soc soc.c
```

Output:

```
"COMPILETIME/file"
```

Build command:

```
cc -Wall -o soc soc.c -DCOMPILETIME=abcd
```

Output:

```
"abcd/file"
```

Tested under gcc 4.9.2.

The problem you are facing with `fopen` could be related to:

```
sprintf(filepath,"\"%s\file\"",strname(COMPILETIME));
                      ^^^^
```

Make that

```
sprintf(filepath,"\"%s\\file\"",strname(COMPILETIME));
                      ^^^^
```

Otherwise, you are escaping the character `f`, which does nothing. You should also be able to use a forward slash instead of a backward slash.

```
sprintf(filepath,"\"%s/file\"",strname(COMPILETIME));
                      ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you, you are correct - however, I've now realized my problem is actually in fopen. When I go with file=fopen(filepath,"a"), I get a segmentation fault. However, if I go back and type in the exact contents of filepath (as it was defined) into my fopen command, re-make and re-run the program, the file is placed correctly (I didn't delete the path folder). So, what's the difference between "timestamp/file" and filepath="timestamp/file"?

Comment: @zjw518, that's a different problem. It will be better to ask that in another SO post.

Comment: You are right, and I resolved it. I'll leave the post up for posterity, I suppose. Thanks!